# Why am I NOT getting a Null Reference Exception?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm using LINQ to Entities to get some data from a database. Below is my query.

```
var location = from l in dbContext.Locations
join e in dbContext.Equipment on l.ID equals e.LocationID into rs1
from e in rs1.DefaultIfEmpty()
where ids.Contains(l.ID)
select new
{
    EquipmentClass = e,
    LocationID = l.ID,
    LocationName = l.Name,
    EquipmentName = e == null ? null : e.Name,
    Description = e == null ? null : e.Description,
    InServiceStatus = e == null ? false : e.InServiceStatus,
    EquipmentType = e.EquipmentType.Name
};

foreach (var item in location)
{
    // some logic
}
```

In the code above, `ids` is a list of ints that I pass in to filter the results. When I get the results, I see that one of the return records has a null `EquipmentClass`. I had performed some null checking but realized that I forgot to do null checking on one of the properties. Now I would expect to get a null reference exception on `EquipmentType = e.EquipmentType.Name` but I don't. To my surprise, it works just fine, and is set to null. My `EquipmentClass` has a property type of `EquipmentType`, which is another class. `EquipmentType` has a `Name` property which is a String.

1. Why doesn't this throw a null reference exception?

Just as a test, I removed the null check from `InServiceStatus = e == null ? false : e.InServiceStatus` and it fails with an invalid operation exception upon running a foreach loop using the query.

2. Does this mean that I only need to do null checking on non-nullable values?

**Update**:

```
foreach (var item in location)
{
    var p = item.EquipmentClass.EquipmentType.Name;
}
```

Added this right after the query. On the assignment of p, I get a null reference exception. I'm not sure how it even gets that far, as it should fail on the first line of the foreach loop. Without the line declaring variable p, **I do not get a null reference exception**. If anyone can explain what is happening I would be grateful. Just for reference, the values of `item.EquipmentClass` and `item.EquipmentType` are both null by the time the foreach loop starts.

**Update2:**
I found [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8d4965e8-6a39-43e1-845c-ff42247ef9f6/defaultifempty-and-referencing-null-object?forum=linqprojectgeneral) where it seems that someone has an almost identical issue using LINQ to SQL. I get the gist of the answer but don't fully understand its potential impact on my two questions above.

Comment: I doubt it is possible. Without null check the code `EquipmentType = e.EquipmentType.Name` will also fail. Are you sure your observation is correct? I tried a quick code sample at my end and it is failing as expected.

Comment: Related post - [Linq join iquery, how to use defaultifempty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19293844/465053)

Comment: @RBT Indeed, running my code doesn't produce any errors, it happily runs `EquipmentType = e.EquipmentType.Name` and just sets all of the values to null (that being, e = null, e.EquipmentType = null, and e.EquipmentType.Name = null).

Comment: Can you please update your post with the definition of `EquipmentClass`?

Comment: I've updated my answer. It'll fail if you do the `foreach` enumeration till the end. It might pass for few initial iterations when corresponding matches are available for join.

Comment: I think that's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13148126

Comment: @kapsi very similar, thank you!

Comment: Related posts - [DefaultIfEmpty - LINQ to SQL vs In Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5638200/465053) & [Null or empty object when LINQ to Entities query returns nothing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/352387/236257)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you write a LINQ query against `IQueryable`, what happens is that the methods that you are calling behind the scenes (such as `Select`, `Where`, etc.) don't do anything more than just recording how you have called them, i.e. they record the predicate expressions and carry over a LINQ provider. As soon as you start iterating the query, *the provider is asked to execute the query model*. So basically, the provider uses the expression model to give you a result of the expected type.

**The provider is by no means required to actually compile or even execute the code (model) you delivered as an expression.** In fact, the whole point of LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities is that the provider does not do this and translate the code expression to SQL instead.

Therefore, your query is actually rendered as an SQL query and the result of that query is translated back. Therefore, the variable `e` that you see in the query is not necessarily really created but only used for the LINQ provider to compile an SQL query. However, most database servers have null propagations.

**Run the same query against LINQ to Objects and you will get your missing NullReferenceException**.

Comment: Would it still be considered good practice to do null checking on nullable values or would that be considered redundant in this case?

Comment: @Sudsy1002 Actually, many databases allow to configure whether they propagate null values, so in the above, your code would depend on that database configuration. Therefore, yes, null checks is a good thing, in case you change the LINQ provider or change the database configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Your update helped me understand your real concern. The concept you need to know in regards to LINQ queries is [deferred execution in LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution#deferred-query-execution).

Please go through below links for more details:

[What are the benefits of a Deferred Execution in LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7324033/465053)

[Linq - What is the quickest way to find out deferred execution or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3894490/465053)

Now what happens in your case? You've stored your query in `location` variable. That particular step is just the initialization part. It doesn't really executes the query on your database through your ORM layer. This is how you can test this.

Put a break point on the line of code where you're initializing `location` variable with LINQ query. When debugger stops in Visual Studio, then go to SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and start a SQL Server Profiler session.

Now press <kbd>F10</kbd> in Visual Studio to step over the code statement. At this point of time you'll see absolutely no query execution in profiler session as shown below:

[image]

That is all because LINQ query didn't get executed at all till this point of time.

Now you reach to your below line of code:

```
foreach (var item in location)
{
    var p = item.EquipmentClass.EquipmentType.Name;
}
```

The moment you enter inside foreach loop, the LINQ query gets fired and you'll see the corresponding log in trace session in SQL Server profiler. So a LINQ query doesn't get fired unless it is being enumerated. This is called deferred execution i.e. the runtime defers the execution until enumeration. If you never enumerate `location` variable in your code then query execution will never happen at all.

So to answer your query, exception will come only when query gets fired. Not before that!

**Update 1**: You're saying that - **I do not get a null reference exception**. Yes! you will *not* get null reference exception until you reach to the record whose corresponding RHS joined record is missing. Have a look at below code for better understanding:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mylist1 = new List<MyClass1>();
        mylist1.Add(new MyClass1 { id = 1, Name1 = "1" });
        mylist1.Add(new MyClass1 { id = 2, Name1 = "2" });

        var mylist2 = new List<MyClass2>();
        mylist2.Add(new MyClass2 { id = 1, Name2 = "1" });

        var location = from l in mylist1
                       join e in mylist2 on l.id equals e.id into rs1
                       from e in rs1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       //where ids.Contains(l.ID)
                       select new
                       {
                           EquipmentClass = e,
                           InServiceStatus = e == null ? 1 : e.id,
                           EquipmentType = e.id
                       };

        foreach (var item in location)
        {

        }
    }
}

class MyClass1
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
}

class MyClass2
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string Name2 { get; set; }
}
```

So, Now when I start iterating the `location` variable, it doesn't breaks in first iteration. It breaks in second iteration. It breaks when it fails to obtain the record/object corresponding to `MyClass1` object having `id` 2 present in `mylist1`. `mylist2` doesn't have any object with `id` 2. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I understand that the query does not execute until it is enumerated, that is not my concern. I *am not* getting a null reference error, *even when the loop is enumerated*. I specifically put in the code above to show that I get the error on the assignment of p, *not the enumeration of the query*. If I were to remove the line with the variable p in my example, I wouldn't get an exception at all.

Comment: Sounds impossible to me but I'll try to resolve your concern. Please share the definition of `EquipmentClass` class.

Comment: My code doesn't break in any iteration, I get through the whole foreach loop without issue. I know what you are saying, and I understand it. I am saying that something completely different is happening in my case. Perhaps it is specific to LINQ to SQL/Entities. I have updated my post with a link to a similar issue. In the answer on that link it seems to indicate that LINQ is manipulating how the data is assigned under the hood, apparently in a way that doesn't result in a null reference exception that you would expect when using objects.

Answer (score -1):

your `e.EquipmentType.Name` is `null` and it is getting assigned to `EquipmentType` and it is perfectly fine to assign `null` to a `nullable` type and  you are using `DefaultIfEmpty()` which will initialize the elements with their default value if it fails to match any condition and in this case your `e.ElementType.Name` is getting set to `null` which is fine I guess. use `ToList()` that will throw the exception.

I hope I am making some sense and you people might have discussed this.

Comment: DefaultIfEmpty is not what allows e.EquipmentType.Name to be a null value. If I was using LINQ to Objects, the same statement would yield a null reference exception. Also my goal was not to get the exception, I wanted to know why I *wasn't* getting the exception.